# Any utility to generate sql template for sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has X columns,

```
timestamp, name, age, income, creditscore, and 60 more indicators..
```

I want to generate a table

```
timestamp, income, last_30_month_income_average, creditscore, 
last_30_month_creditscore_average, and 60 more.
```

Say I know how to write this for one indicator

```
select income, avg()over(partition by name ....) from data
```

How do I generate a query for 60 more of these columns?

Is there some kind of template language for this kind of task?

Comment: No.  You add each column that you want.  You can generate the code in a spreadsheet or using a SQL query if you like.